# Call to BeginPaint via PInvoke returning empty update region in PAINTSTRUCT

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I have been working on creating a custom `RichTextBox` control to add some additional graphics to the text area.  From what I've been reading, this control does not expose its Paint event by default.

I followed a suggestion on MSDN ([Painting on a RichTextBox Control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3521ad3-7ceb-4019-b3ba-441aae1f5a41/painting-on-a-richtextbox-control?forum=vblanguage) ) to re-expose the Paint event and create an `OnPaint` event handler which is triggered by the `WM_PAINT` message.

In the `OnPaint` method, I'm trying to call `BeginPaint()` from the Win32 API to draw some shapes, but nothing is being drawn.  When I inspect the `rcPaint` field inside of the `PAINTSTRUCT` struct, it's always empty (all values are 0).  So my question is, why is the update region always empty?  I must be missing something.

Relevant code:

```
public partial class RichTextBoxEnhanced : RichTextBox
{

    private PAINTSTRUCT ps;


    new public void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var hdc = BeginPaint(this.Handle,  out ps);

        FillRect(hdc, ref ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(100));

        Rectangle(hdc, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000);

        EndPaint(this.Handle, ref ps);

        Paint?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr BeginPaint(IntPtr hwnd, out PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EndPaint(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateSolidBrush(uint crColor);
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that by the time `OnPaint()` is called, .net has already called `BeginPaint()` for you to populate the `PaintEventArgs`, and so the returned DC might be `NULL` (to indicate failure)...

Comment: @andlabs, this was indeed the issue.  Apparently base.WndPrc was calling BeginPaint before reaching my OnPaint method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  @andlabs comment lead me to look at my overridden `WndProc` method.  My painting method was called after `base.WndProc(ref msg)` which apparently performs `BeginPaint`.  Moving my `OnPaint()` method above corrected the issue.

Wrong code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT:
                    mBaseControl.Invalidate();
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    OnPaint();
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Correct code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT:
                    mBaseControl.Invalidate();
                    OnPaint();
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: My suggestion would have been to just use the `Graphics` object in the `PaintEventArgs`. Does that not work?

Comment: Yes, that works.  I am just experimenting with BeginPaint.

Comment: All right. One important thing to note about `BeginPaint()` is that it validates the update rect, so if you call it twice in the same `WM_PAINT` call, you'll get different update rect values. Indeed, it is the presence of an update rect that determines whether `WM_PAINT` gets generated or not, so `BeginPaint()` tells Windows "okay, we're painting now; no need to worry about any more `WM_PAINT`s until the next time the update rect changes".

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through `WndProc` and allow the control to do its default painting. You can use `Graphics` object for the painting. Example:

```
public partial class MyRichEdit : RichTextBox
{
    public MyRichEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.Msg)
        {
            case 15://WM_PAINT
                base.WndProc(ref msg);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, 10, 10);
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmak.  I did testing using the Graphics class and this worked fine, but when I wanted to test with the BeginPaint method is where I ran into a problem.  I didn't know that base.WndProc already called BeginPaint, so I had to change my logic to call my OnPaint method before.